# com.google.android.geo.API_KEY Not recogniced by API level 26

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm triying to develop an app with API 26 (Android 8.0) using Place autocomplete, to use it i need to add a Google Maps api. I've followed the steps of this guide https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key?hl=es-419 and when I try to use the API on the code it does not recognice geo. It says this:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), com.google.android.geo.API_KEY);
```

What can I do? Thanks a lot!

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AforumControl">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AforumControl.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="${API_KEY}" />

</application>
```

Local properties:

```
    ## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file should *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=/home/myuser/Android/Sdk
API_KEY=my-api-key
```

The line of code giving problems in MainActivity.java

```
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), com.google.android.geo.API_KEY);
```

Comment: XML code? where are you calling API?

Comment: In MainActivity.java, wait a minute, i'll edit the code

Comment: can it be that you need to replace "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" with your own API key?

Comment: No, because if you follow the guide I put on the post, it says it safer to store it in local.properties